# Cast an int array to string, then print with printf, without allocating new memory

Tags: c

I thought I had this solved, but apparently, I was incorrect.  The question is... what did I miss?

**Assignment description:**

**You are to create a C program which fills an integer array with integers and then you are to cast it as a string and print it out.**  The output of the string should be your first and last name with proper capitalization, spacing and punctuation.  Your program should have structure similar to:

```
main()
{

     int A[100];
     char *S;

A[0]=XXXX;
A[1]=YYYY;

...

A[n]=0;  -- because C strings are terminated with NULL

...

printf("My name is %s\n",S);

}
```

**Response to my submission:**

You still copied memory cells to other, which is not expected. You use different space for the integer array as the string which does not follow the requirements. Please follow the instructions carefully next time.

**My submission**

*Note that the first time I submitted, I simply used malloc on S, and copied casted values from A to S.*  ***The response was that I could not use malloc or allocate new space.***  This requirement was not in the problem description above.

Below was my second and final submission, which is the submission being referred to in the submission response above.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Main Program*/
int main (int arga, char **argb){
    int A[100];
    char *S;
    A[0] = 68;
    A[1] = 117; 
    /** etc. etc. etc. **/
    A[13] = 115;
    A[14] = 0;
    // Point a char pointer to the first integer
    S = (char *) A;
    // For generality, in C, [charSize == 1 <= intSize]
    // This is the ratio of intSize over charSize
    int ratio = sizeof(int);
    // Copy the i'th (char sized) set of bytes into
    // consecutive locations in memory.
    int i = 0;
    // Using the char pointer as our reference, each set of
    // bits is then i*ratio positions away from the i'th
    // consecutive position in which it belongs for a string.
    while (S[i*ratio] != 0){
        S[i] = S[i*ratio];
        i++;
    }
    // a sentinel for the 'S string'
    S[i] = 0;
    printf("My name is %s\n", S);
    return 0;
}// end main
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've got the core idea down: the space for one integer will hold many chars. I believe you just need to pack the integer array "by hand" instead of in the for loop. Assuming a 4-byte integer on a little-endian machine, give this a shot.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int x[50];
  x[0] = 'D' | 'u' << 8 | 's' << 16 | 't' << 24;
  x[1] = 0;
  char *s = (char*)x;
  printf("Name: %s\n", s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This invokes undefined behavior. the initializing part is awfully under u/b and you want to change that.

Comment: The integer isn't unsigned, may result in overflow.

Comment: @Malina: Not for a 32-bit `int` type with ASCII or ISO 8859-x or Unicode of CP1252 or related code sets (as opposed to, say, EBCDIC).

Comment: @Malina I don't see how overflow here is of any concern. He's just sticking the bytes into the integer. Overflow isn't relevant because he's going to be iterating over it with a `char *` anyways.

Comment: I thought about using this approach, but I wanted to get as far away as possible from turning in this: printf("%s", "My Name, basically typed out, as opposed to computed, and casted")

Comment: The integer composing code, however, needs explicit parenthesis around the different byte shifts.

Comment: @DustinCharles: But the template you're given has the XXXX and YYYY placeholders, so that's more or less what's expected, is it not?

Comment: @RussSchultz: Why?  Stylistically, it would be better, yes — but that's not the same as _needing_ explicit parentheses.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, most compilers will at least warn you if you try to do this without parenthesis. It's not technically *required*, but it's definitely the standard to include parentheses around shift operations.

Comment: I wouldn't prefer to use bitwise computations for the initialization of an integer. I would use something like that. `int p = *(int*)"star";` I don't know it was just all that non type-safety, relative specifications and so forth. But as I said.. I would use union after all.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I always put parens around them because i'm generally doing bitstuffing with masks.   I also find it a lot easier to mentally parse when things are explicitly grouped.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 0032 works fine for me too.  I think my solution is fine, and I should have been awarded full credit.  I do like 0x74737544.  I essentially let my code type  0x74737544 for me.  And my solution will work on more platforms that it would have worked on had I taken that approach.  To each their own, I guess.  But I think that my program is more correct than is the response to my submission.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your professor wanted you to put 4 bytes into each `int` instead of having an array of `n` "1 byte" ints that you later condensed into `4 / sizeof(int)` bytes using the while loop. Per Hurkyl's comment, the solution to this assignment would be platform dependent, meaning that it will differ from machine to machine. I'm assuming your instructor had the class ssh into and use a specific machine?

In any case, assuming you're on a little endian machine, say you wanted to type out the string: "Hi Dad!". Then a snippet of the solution would look something like this:

```
// Precursor stuff
A[0] = 0x44206948; // Hi D
A[1] = 0x216461; // ad!
A[2] = 0; // Null terminated
char *S = (char *)A;

printf("My string: %s\n", S);
// Other stuff
```

Comment: This is definitely something that I may have missed.  You may absolutely be correct.  However, if you are correct, then my solution was incorrect, only because I used a computational procedure to do what I could have essentially typed out instead?  

*Mind blown

Comment: Yup, that's right! Kind of sucks, but it's a good lesson to learn because it's really the way you should be thinking about C (and systems in general). It really all comes down to bytes and context. For example, as you continue your foray into C you'll learn that files are really just sequences of bytes (yes, that goes for directories, sockets, etc). There's plenty more mind blowing to come, trust me.

Comment: By the way, you get get around the endianness issue by using `ntohl()` to reorder your ideal view of the bytes to local architecture.   That function is found in `#include <netinet/in.h>` (generally)